# Only include enabled objects in dict() - Python

Tags: python

I am current converting a list of Objects to a dict using this command:

```
MODULES = dict([(s.key, s) for s in ALL_MODULES])
```

Each module in ALL_MODULES is enabled=True or enabled=False

How would I change the above code to only include the modules with enabled=True?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
MODULES = dict([(s.key, s) for s in ALL_MODULES if s.enabled])
```

or

```
MODULES = dict([(s.key, s) for s in ALL_MODULES if s['enabled']])
```

Depends on module data type.

Answer (score 1):

```
MODULES = dict([(s.key, s) for s in ALL_MODULES if MODULES['enabled'] == True])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict([(s.key, s) for s in ALL_MODULES if enabled==True])
```